# IoT device connection with Azure IoT hub without certificate

Tags: azure, cloud, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

We are having a IoT controller device  and we want to connect it with Azure IoT hub (via MQTT) so is it possible to send data from IoT device to Azure IoT hub without installing any certificate on device i.e. we can configure a URL on device and that will simply send data to cloud with any certificate configuration on device. This is for testing purpose in the production we will update it with SSL.

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Is your proposal to connect with "any" certificate, or to temporary use no certificate?

Comment: Thanks for response,Temporary use with out any certificate

Comment: Have you tried using symmetric access keys? Or are these not an option for you? Also, what programming language are you using?

Comment: I am new to the IoT and do not have any prior knowledge of hardware devices. I know other Microsoft technologies. Currently I have a device which is MQTT supported as per local manufacturer  and I have a URL/IP configuration option at device level I can not update firmware or any thing on device except URL configuration. I have to connect this to azure IoT if feasible. I am going through the Azure IoT documentation they recommend to use SSL/TLS for secure connection so I just what help to know whether we can connect device without certificate programming on device.Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device